# How to extract data from an XML column using t-sql without using singletons and using the value instead

Tags: xml, t-sql

Here is my XML:

```
<IW version="2.0">
  <Quote QuoteId="23612301" PackageId="9" EffectiveDate="12/20/2020">
    <Vehicle VehicleId="42142117" DriverId="119147457" Description="2014 Nissan MAXIMA S/MAXIMA SV Sedan 4-Dr ">
      <Feature Value="BI" Premium="58">
        <Factor>
          <Relativity>Discount Combo</Relativity>
          <RelativityKey>12YYY</RelativityKey>
          <Value>0.45</Value>
          <Rounding>3</Rounding>
          <Order>18</Order>
          <SubFactors>
            <Discount>
              **<Modifier>Prior - 12 months</Modifier>**
              <Value>1</Value>
            </Discount>
            <Discount>
              <Modifier>Multi Car</Modifier>
              <Value>1</Value>
            </Discount>
            <Discount>
              <Modifier>In Agency</Modifier>
              <Value>1</Value>
            </Discount>
            <Discount>
              **<Modifier>Homeowner</Modifier>**
              <Value>1</Value>
            </Discount>
          </SubFactors>
        </Factor>
      </Feature>
    </Vehicle>
  </Quote>
</IW>
```

I eliminated the issue of using a singleton and just get the values of each "Prior - # months" Modifier and "Homeowner" in the Xml and put this into a CTE statement to limit the data that I'm looking for.  The code below fixed my issue.  Hope it helps someone else.  Thanks.

**Here is the code that I'm using that fixed my original question**:

```
SELECT r.QuoteFactorsSysId, r.QFSysDate, r.PolicySysID, r.PolicyNo, r.PackageSysID, r.BindDate
    , ISNULL(x.y.value('(SubFactors/Discount[Modifier="Prior - 6 months"]/Value)[1]','varchar(max)'),0) as [Prior - 6 months]
    , ISNULL(x.y.value('(SubFactors/Discount[Modifier="Prior - 12 months"]/Value)[1]','varchar(max)'),0) as [Prior - 12 months]
    , ISNULL(x.y.value('(SubFactors/Discount[Modifier="Prior - 24 months"]/Value)[1]','varchar(max)'),0) as [Prior - 24 months]
    , ISNULL(x.y.value('(SubFactors/Discount[Modifier="Homeowner"]/Value)[1]','varchar(max)'),0) as Homeowner   
    , r.FactorXml 
FROM #tempMaxQuoteFactorRecords r
    CROSS APPLY r.FactorXml.nodes('IW/Quote/Vehicle/Feature/Factor') as x(y)
WHERE x.y.value('(Relativity)[1]', 'varchar(max)') = 'Discount Combo'
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please share your desired output.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky, I actually fixed my problem.  I'll fix the SELECT statement above to show what fixed my problem.  Thanks for taking time to ask your question.

Comment: Good to hear that you resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a string-based approach that could be an alternative for smaller sets of records.  This should be considered a more "*hackish*" approach to solving the problem.

The solution starts with a function that will take the XML as a string.  The function will assume that the nodes are always in the same order.  If not, the results will be incorrect.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.FN_FindValue(@xml NVARCHAR(MAX), @node NVARCHAR(500), @seek NVARCHAR(500))
    RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @len INT;
    DECLARE @index INT;
    
    SET @xml = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@xml , ' ', ''), CHAR(13), ''), CHAR(10), ''), CHAR(9), '');
    SET @len = LEN(@node+@seek);
    SET @index = CHARINDEX(@node, @xml);

    RETURN (SELECT SUBSTRING(@xml, @index + @len, 1))
END
GO
```

The function first flattens the provided XML by removing all spaces, carriage returns, linefeeds, and tabs.  Then obtains the length and position of the sought after strings.  Because the values being sought are either 1 or 0, the substring function can easily pull the value being sought.

Here is how it would look being put to use against a single XML element:

```
DECLARE @xml NVARCHAR(MAX) = '<IW version="2.0">
  <Quote QuoteId="23612301" PackageId="9" EffectiveDate="12/20/2020">
    <Vehicle VehicleId="42142117" DriverId="119147457" Description="2014 Nissan MAXIMA S/MAXIMA SV Sedan 4-Dr ">
      <Feature Value="BI" Premium="58">
        <Factor>
          <Relativity>Discount Combo</Relativity>
          <RelativityKey>12YYY</RelativityKey>
          <Value>0.45</Value>
          <Rounding>3</Rounding>
          <Order>18</Order>
          <SubFactors>
            <Discount>
              <Modifier>Prior - 12 months</Modifier>
              <Value>1</Value>
            </Discount>
            <Discount>
              <Modifier>Multi Car</Modifier>
              <Value>1</Value>
            </Discount>
            <Discount>
              <Modifier>In Agency</Modifier>
              <Value>1</Value>
            </Discount>
            <Discount>
              <Modifier>Homeowner</Modifier>
              <Value>1</Value>
            </Discount>
          </SubFactors>
        </Factor>
      </Feature>
    </Vehicle>
  </Quote>
</IW>';

DECLARE @node NVARCHAR(500) = '<Modifier>Homeowner</Modifier>';
DECLARE @seek NVARCHAR(500) = '<Value>';

SELECT dbo.FN_FindValue(@xml, @node, @seek);
```

Granted this may not be an option for you given the certain reduction in performance a string-based approach may incur versus using SQL's built-in XML support, I find this more readable and for smaller cases, perhaps a valid approach.

Comment: Wayne, SQL Server has XML data type and XQuery language as API to handle XML chores. It is not a good idea to stoop down to XML manipulation as a string.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky, I agree with you 100%.  That is why I called this a more "hackish" approach and stated the performance reduction would cause this to not be a good option in most cases.  However, in edge cases and where the data is known, this could be an approach for those not as familiar with XQuery.